# What is the best way to make an approximating function out of this list?

Tags: interpolation

What is a good way to make an "InterpolatingFunction" from the following list represented on the Graphs?
The small part that appears on the second graph is what causes the problems.The Goal is to create a monotonic function that is a good approximation to the list, like the one I made manually in the third graph.

The following list includes the problematic part:

```
 {{6.46422,67.3468},{6.49531,67.5314},{6.52647,67.7161},{6.5577,67.9008},{6.589,68.0856},{6.62038,68.2704},{6.65182,68.4554},{6.68334,68.6404},{6.71494,68.8255},{6.7466,69.0107},{6.77834,69.196},{6.81015,69.3813},{6.84203,69.5668},{6.87398,69.7523},{6.906,69.9378},{6.9381,70.1235},{6.97027,70.3092},{7.00251,70.495},{7.03483,70.6809},{7.06721,70.8669},{7.09967,71.0529},{7.1322,71.239},{7.1648,71.4252},{7.19747,71.6115},{7.23022,71.7978},{7.26304,71.9843},{7.29593,72.1708},{7.32889,72.3573},{7.36193,72.544},{7.39503,72.7307},{7.42821,72.9175},{7.46146,73.1044},{7.49478,73.2914},{7.52818,73.4784},{7.56164,73.6656},{7.59518,73.8528},{7.62879,74.04},{7.66247,74.2274},{7.69623,74.4148},{7.73005,74.6023},{7.76395,74.7899},{7.79792,74.9776},{7.83196,75.1653},{7.86579,75.3531},{7.89037,75.541},{7.89105,75.7289},{7.88383,75.9168},{7.88152,76.1047},{7.87961,76.2926},{7.87784,76.4805},{7.87625,76.6684},{7.87478,76.8562},{7.87343,77.0441},{7.87217,77.232},{7.87101,77.4198},{7.86993,77.6077},{7.86893,77.7956},{7.86799,77.9834},{7.86712,78.1713},{7.86631,78.3591},{7.86556,78.547},{7.86487,78.7348},{7.86422,78.9227},{7.86363,79.1105},{7.86309,79.2984},{7.86259,79.4862},{7.86214,79.6741},{7.86174,79.8619},{7.86137,80.0498},{7.86105,80.2376},{7.86077,80.4255},{7.86052,80.6133},{7.86032,80.8011},{7.86015,80.989},{7.86002,81.1768},{7.85993,81.3647},{7.85987,81.5525},{7.85985,81.7404},{7.85986,81.9282},{7.8599,82.116},{7.85998,82.3039},{7.86009,82.4917},{7.86024,82.6796},{7.86041,82.8674},{7.86062,83.0552},{7.86085,83.2431},{7.86112,83.4309},{7.86142,83.6188},{7.86175,83.8066},{7.8621,83.9945},{7.86249,84.1823},{7.86291,84.3702},{7.86335,84.558},{7.86382,84.7459},{7.86433,84.9337},{7.86486,85.1216},{7.86541,85.3094},{7.866,85.4973},{7.86661,85.6851},{7.86725,85.873},{7.86792,86.0608},{7.86861,86.2487},{7.86933,86.4365},{7.87008,86.6244},{7.87085,86.8123},{7.87165,87.0001},{7.87247,87.188},{7.87332,87.3759},{7.8742,87.5637},{7.8751,87.7516},{7.87603,87.9395},{7.87698,88.1274},{7.87796,88.3152},{7.87896,88.5031},{7.87999,88.691},{7.88105,88.8789},{7.88212,89.0668},{7.88323,89.2546},{7.88435,89.4425},{7.8855,89.6304},{7.88668,89.8183},{7.88788,90.0062},{7.88911,90.1941},{7.89035,90.382},{7.89163,90.5699},{7.89292,90.7578},{7.89424,90.9457},{7.89559,91.1336},{7.89696,91.3215},{7.89835,91.5095},{7.89976,91.6974},{7.9012,91.8853},{7.90266,92.0732},{7.90415,92.2611},{7.90566,92.4491},{7.90719,92.637},{7.90875,92.8249},{7.91033,93.0129},{7.91193,93.2008},{7.91355,93.3888},{7.9152,93.5767},{7.91687,93.7647},{7.91857,93.9526},{7.92028,94.1406},{7.92202,94.3285},{7.92379,94.5165},{7.92557,94.7045},{7.92738,94.8924},{7.92921,95.0804},{7.93106,95.2684},{7.93294,95.4564},{7.93484,95.6443},{7.93676,95.8323},{7.9387,96.0203},{7.94067,96.2083},{7.94266,96.3963},{7.94467,96.5843},{7.9467,96.7723},{7.94876,96.9603},{7.95084,97.1483},{7.95294,97.3363},{7.95506,97.5244},{7.95721,97.7124},{7.95937,97.9004},{7.96156,98.0884},{7.96378,98.2765},{7.96601,98.4645},{7.96827,98.6525},{7.97054,98.8406},{7.97284,99.0286},{7.97517,99.2167},{7.97751,99.4048},{7.97988,99.5928},{7.98227,99.7809},{7.98468,99.9689},{7.98711,100.157},{7.98956,100.345},{7.99204,100.533},{7.99454,100.721},{7.99706,100.909},{7.9996,101.097},{8.00216,101.286},{8.00475,101.474},{8.00736,101.662},{8.00999,101.85},{8.01264,102.038},{8.01531,102.226},{8.01801,102.414},{8.02072,102.602},{8.02346,102.791},{8.02622,102.979},{8.02901,103.167},{8.03181,103.355},{8.03464,103.543},{8.03748,103.731},{8.04035,103.919},{8.04324,104.108},{8.04616,104.296},{8.04909,104.484},{8.05205,104.672},{8.05502,104.86},{8.05802,105.049},{8.06105,105.237},{8.06409,105.425},{8.06715,105.613},{8.07024,105.801},{8.07335,105.99},{8.07648,106.178},{8.07963,106.366},{8.0828,106.554},{8.086,106.743},{8.08921,106.931},{8.09245,107.119},{8.09571,107.307},{8.09899,107.496},{8.10229,107.684},{8.10562,107.872},{8.10896,108.06},{8.11233,108.249},{8.11572,108.437},{8.11913,108.625},{8.12257,108.814},{8.12602,109.002},{8.1295,109.19},{8.13299,109.378},{8.13651,109.567},{8.14005,109.755},{8.14362,109.943},{8.1472,110.132},{8.15081,110.32},{8.15443,110.508},{8.15808,110.697},{8.16175,110.885},{8.16544,111.074},{8.16916,111.262},{8.17289,111.45},{8.17665,111.639},{8.18043,111.827},{8.18423,112.015},{8.18805,112.204},{8.19189,112.392},{8.19576,112.581},{8.19965,112.769},{8.20356,112.958},{8.20749,113.146},{8.21144,113.334},{8.21541,113.523},{8.21941,113.711},{8.22342,113.9},{8.22746,114.088},{8.23152,114.277},{8.2356,114.465},{8.23971,114.654},{8.24383,114.842},{8.24798,115.031},{8.25215,115.219},{8.25634,115.408},{8.26055,115.596},{8.26478,115.785},{8.26904,115.973},{8.27332,116.162},{8.27761,116.35},{8.28193,116.539},{8.28628,116.727},{8.29064,116.916},{8.29503,117.105},{8.29943,117.293},{8.30386,117.482},{8.30831,117.67},{8.31279,117.859},{8.31728,118.048},{8.3218,118.236},{8.32634,118.425},{8.3309,118.613},{8.33548,118.802},{8.34008,118.991},{8.3447,119.179},{8.34935,119.368},{8.35402,119.557},{8.35871,119.745},{8.36342,119.934},{8.36816,120.123},{8.37291,120.311},{8.37769,120.5},{8.38249,120.689},{8.38731,120.877},{8.39216,121.066},{8.39702,121.255},{8.40191,121.444},{8.40682,121.632},{8.41175,121.821},{8.4167,122.01},{8.42168,122.198},{8.42667,122.387},{8.43169,122.576},{8.43673,122.765},{8.44179,122.954},{8.44688,123.142},{8.45198,123.331},{8.45711,123.52},{8.46226,123.709},{8.46743,123.898},{8.47263,124.086},{8.47784,124.275},{8.48308,124.464},{8.48834,124.653},{8.49362,124.842},{8.49893,125.031},{8.50425,125.22},{8.5096,125.408},{8.51497,125.597},{8.52037,125.786},{8.52578,125.975},{8.53122,126.164},{8.53667,126.353},{8.54215,126.542},{8.54766,126.731},{8.55318,126.92},{8.55873,127.109},{8.5643,127.298},{8.56989,127.487},{8.5755,127.676},{8.58114,127.865},{8.58679,128.054},{8.59247,128.243},{8.59818,128.432},{8.6039,128.621},{8.60965,128.81},{8.61541,128.999},{8.6212,129.188},{8.62702,129.377},{8.63285,129.566},{8.63871,129.755},{8.64459,129.944},{8.65049,130.133},{8.65641,130.322},{8.66236,130.511},{8.66833,130.7},{8.67432,130.889},{8.68033,131.078},{8.68637,131.268},{8.69242,131.457},{8.6985,131.646},{8.70461,131.835},{8.71073,132.024},{8.71688,132.213},{8.72305,132.402},{8.72924,132.592},{8.73545,132.781},{8.74169,132.97},{8.74795,133.159}}
```

[image: 1st Graph]
[image: 2nd Graph]
[image: 3rd Graph]

Comment: Is the first plot relevant for this interpolation???

Comment: It is the list I want to make a function of.

Comment: Make it in 2 parts, combine a straight line with an interpolating function

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide your data list!

Comment: How can I do that? I have a dat file.

Comment: @L.P. Just copy&paste the list from Mathematica in your question, highlight the list  and click the `{}`

Comment: ok ill do that for only that specific part so the list won't be to large

Answer (score 1):

```
{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]

(* {6.46422, 8.74795} *)
```

The model and constraints

```
mcc = {Piecewise[{{a1*x + b1, x < k}},
    a2*x^3 + b2*x^2 + c2*x + d2],
   a1*k + b1 == a2*k^3 + b2*k^2 + c2*k + d2,
   7.5 < k < 7.9};

(nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, mcc,
    {a1, b1, {k, 7.7}, a2, b2, c2, d2}, x]) // Normal
```

[image]

```
Show[
 Plot[nlm[x], {x, xmin, xmax}],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Red]]]
```

[image]

Comment: What I ended up doing is somewhat similar. I split the list in three parts where the middle part is the one that caused the problem, it was possible after i found a way to calculate the point where the anomaly happens, this is important because my code is producing many lists of this type, not only one. So for the first and third part I just use Interpolation[] and for the middle part I used a polynomial fitting with FindFit[] and i got this idea from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a function `x->y=f[x]` try `BezierCurve`

```
Graphics [{BezierCurve[data], Red, Point[data]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]